# Prevent 'cp' from outputting the file name from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a shell script which copies a few files to the current directory, compresses them, and streams the compressed file to stdout.

On the client side I use plink to execute the script and stream stdin to a file.

This almost works.

It seems that the cp command outputs the file name being copied when its executed from inside the script. If I execute '**cp /path/to/file1 .**' in the shell it does it quietly; if I execute it in a script it outputs "file1".

How do I prevent this? I've tried piping the output of the cp command to /dev/null and to a dummy text file but with no luck.

thanks for any help.

#### the script

```
#!/bin/bash

cp /path/to/file1 .
cp /path/to/file2 .
cp /path/to/file3 .

tar -cvzf package.tgz file1 file2 file3

cat package.tgz
```

#### the output

```
file1
file2
file3
<<binary data>>
```

Comment: If you want the tar output, why not removing the -f package.tgz and letting tar print it directly to stdout?

Comment: What he said. (remove the -f and -v options)

Comment: @Ken G: and remove the cat package.tgz at the end, of course.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not cp, it's tar. You are passing it -v, which makes it print the names of the files.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! I'd always assumed that the file names emitted by tar go to `stderr`, but that isn't always the case: only if you write your tar file to `stdout` do the files written by `-v` go to `stderr`:

```
$ tar cvf - share > /dev/null
share/                         # this must be going
share/.DS_Store                # to stderr since we
share/man/                     # redirected stdout to
share/man/.DS_Store            # /dev/null above.
share/man/man1/
share/man/man1/diffmerge.man1
```

The counter-example:

```
$ tar cvf blah.tar share > /dev/null
```

This produced no list of file names because they got sent to `/dev/null`. 
I guess you learn something new every day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the -v (verbose) option to tar is kicking out the file names to STDERR.  You can also make your script more efficient by having tar write the compressed file stream to STDOUT:

```
tar zcf - file1 file2 file3
```

In this example, the "-" option passed as the filename makes tar write the output to STDOUT.